# pandas + pyodbc ODBC SQL type -150 is not yet supported

Tags: sql-server, pandas, odbc, pyodbc

I know there is many topics on this but i think this is much specific.
I get the current code for audit purpose:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

query = """
--Top 50 high total CPU Queries
SELECT TOP 50
'High CPU Queries' as Type,
serverproperty('machinename') as 'Server Name',
isnull(serverproperty('instancename'),serverproperty('machinename')) as 'Instance Name',
        COALESCE(DB_NAME(qt.dbid),
        DB_NAME(CAST(pa.value as int)), 
        'Resource') AS DBNAME,
    qs.execution_count as [Execution Count],
    qs.total_worker_time/1000 as [Total CPU Time],
    (qs.total_worker_time/1000)/qs.execution_count as [Avg CPU Time],
    qs.total_elapsed_time/1000 as [Total Duration],
    (qs.total_elapsed_time/1000)/qs.execution_count as [Avg Duration],
    qs.total_physical_reads as [Total Physical Reads],
    qs.total_physical_reads/qs.execution_count as [Avg Physical Reads],
    qs.total_logical_reads as [Total Logical Reads],
    qs.total_logical_reads/qs.execution_count as [Avg Logical Reads],
SUBSTRING(qt.text,qs.statement_start_offset/2, 
        (case when qs.statement_end_offset = -1 
        then len(convert(nvarchar(max), qt.text)) * 2 
        else qs.statement_end_offset end -qs.statement_start_offset)/2)
        as query_text     
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) as qt
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) qp
    outer APPLY sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle) pa
    where attribute = 'dbid'   
    ORDER BY 
        [Total CPU Time] DESC
"""
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
cnxn.execute(query).fetchall()
cnxn.close()
```

I get the following error:

> > > > cnxn.execute(sql_status_20).fetchall()
> > > >         Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > > >         pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('ODBC SQL type -150 is not yet supported.  column-index=1  type=-150', 'HY106')

Anyone can help me to handle this ? I have the same problem with many SQL Server audit scripts using dates and i can't change the driver as i have all kind of SQL versions in my production env.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it would be difficult to change the existing queries to explicitly CAST or CONVERT the troublesome values then you might consider trying to use a pyodbc [Output Converter Function](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function). It enables you to define a Python function that will be applied to the raw bytes returned for a given ODBC SQL type.

For example, this test code fails with the error you describe:

```python
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SQLmyDb', autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

server_name = crsr.execute("SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('machinename')").fetchval()
print(server_name)

crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

but this works correctly for me under Python3

```python
import pyodbc


def handle_sql_variant_as_string(value):
    return value.decode('utf-16le')


cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SQLmyDb', autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

cnxn.add_output_converter(-150, handle_sql_variant_as_string)
server_name = crsr.execute("SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('machinename')").fetchval()
print(server_name)

crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Answer (score 8):

If you can't change the driver, you'll need to change the query to return data types it supports.

SQL type -150 is `SQL_VARIANT`, which is returned by `SERVERPROPERTY`. The workaround is to explicitly `CAST` the column to a supported type like `nvarchar`:

```
CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('machinename') AS nvarchar(100)) AS 'Server Name',
CAST(ISNULL(SERVERPROPERTY('instancename'),SERVERPROPERTY('machinename')) AS nvarchar(100)) AS 'Instance Name',
```